# Apache 2 could not bind, address already in use

Tags: apache2

I installed Apache 2 on Ubuntu 12.10. When I try to start the service using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`, I get the following message.

```
*Starting web server apache2
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.                                 [fail]
```

Comment: Make sure apache is not already running when (`ps -ef | grep apache`). And what does `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` say?  Verify you have your a site in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and check the files in there.

Answer (score 3):

It's well possible that you have something already running at (or "bound to") that port. Try this command to see processes in question:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

This lists processes listening on port 80. Once you found the culprit you know which process to `kill` or `kill -9` (also as superuser).

Keep in mind that the Apache instance, assuming you had started that earlier, might have gone "stale" or become a zombie. In the latter case even a reboot may be necessary in some cases.

Otherwise go with the answer from dedunumax.

Comment: i have installed apache with ngnix , after remove nginx fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo service apache2 start`

then type

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

second command will display whether it is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message with the following configuration:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   foo
...

# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo
<VirtualHost foo:80>
...

# cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf 
...
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen localhost:80
...
```

Changing `ports.conf` to the following solved the problem:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this as an apache error message with the following configuration:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I commented out the ::1 entry and issued an apache restart command.

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6


# sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other software like Nginx might be running and using port 80.

Apache2 crashed on my VPS with the same message error, and I found that Nginx was present on the server and something (a cron job?) had it started a few days later. This provokes a conflict since it uses port :80 and somehow takes priority over Apache2.

To check if anything is already using port :80, type:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

I solved it by uninstalling Nginx (with "remove --purge"), killing the nginx process, and restarting Apache2.